# Android HTTPClient sometimes slow connecting?

Tags: android, performance, apache-httpclient-4.x

I seem to be having issues with the Android HTTPClient some times its super fast and other times it can take a good few seconds to return a result or says connection refused.

As a test I have tried different web hosts and direct IP also with no effect, testing is on a device connected via wifi.

The code is also running on a thread so not on the main thread.

The code i am using is as follows:

```
String strURL = "http://www.example.com/webservice/index.php";

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "saveFave"));
nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rid", strID));

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "AppName_Android");

DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(strURL);

try {
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


try {
    hc.setRedirectHandler(null);
    HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);
    Log.d("Http Post Response:", rp.toString());

    if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)            
         jsonData = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);

         Log.v(TAG, "JSON Response " + jsonData );

} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.v(TAG, "error " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to tweek the timeouts in debug to throw errors so you can get more data on the cause...

```
    this.config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(6 * 1000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30 * 1000)
        .setSocketTimeout(30 * 1000)                
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behaviour on networks. I see it every day. Sometimes the first connection is fast but mostly slow. The next request goes often faster but not always. It can go slower too. For speed there is no guarantee.